# Get full site home URL in Kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I installed Kohana (in a "kohana" directory in my xampp public folder) and I'm trying to get the full base URL with the domain and protocol.

When I try:

```
url::base();
```

I only get `/kohana/` back as a result, but want `http://localhost/kohana/` instead.

Is it possible to do this in Kohana, or must I use standard PHP?

Answer (score 12):

You don't have to extend anything, just use `URL::site` with the `protocol` parameter:

```
$base_url = URL::site(NULL, TRUE);
```

This will generate a base URL with the current protocol. If you want to use a specific protocol:

```
$base_url = URL::site(NULL, 'http');
```

No need to reinvent the wheel here!

Comment: Ah, I learned something. My (wrong) answer wrongfully assumed I had to set it all up in config (which I did for Kohana 2.3)

Comment: why do I have to use protocol parameter? how protocol is related to full url showing?

Comment: The problem is it adds `/index.php/`to the end (even though I use clean urls (http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls)).